# How to measure Fortran Code metrics in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, code-metrics

How to measure code metrics (Maintainability Index, Cyclomatic Complexity, etc.) of an Intel visual Fortran project ?

We are using Intel Parallel Studio 18 with Visual Studio 2017. The measurement seems possible with other languages.